# Interaction between two tabs of one application possible with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, service

is the following scenario possible?

Let's say we have one application and I open 2 different parts of the application in 2 different tabs in my browser. Is it now possible to have one part of the application in some kind of "Listening Mode" so when I make changes in one part of the application it instantly implements the changes in the other part and the tab automatically refreshes and shows the changes just the way it happens when you would do all the stuff in only one part of the application in one single tab ?

PS: I am referring to the Angular 2 framework.

Comment: yes. you can setup observables from your service, and have both components subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use plain javascript. There is [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage) for this, the event traces changes at storages. Make a service like this

```
$(window).on('storage', storageChanged);
function storageChanged(){
    //all your tabs will listen this event    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about two separate browser tabs, I don't think so. However, I can think of a way you can listen to changes done to storage. In this case one of the tabs is changing a storage item and the other one is listening to the same item and applies them:

```
$(window).on('storage', storage_changed);

function storage_changed(event)
{
  if (ev.originalEvent.key != 'youritemname') return; // ignore other changes
  var message = JSON.parse(ev.originalEvent.newValue);
  if (!message) return; 

  //apply the changes to the second tab

}
```

If your tabs are not using the same code you will need to add the code to both, otherwise that would be enough.

Now when the item with name `youritemname` changes, an event is fired and both tabs can listen to this and act upon that.

The good thing is that you won't even need to read the storage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not because each tab will open a brand new Angular instance and it's not shared.